Lua: How to load/install module json?
I try to use JSON in Lua - I am completely new to Lua.
My code (test.lua)
local json = require ("json")
print "hello"

My install (Debian 12)
# luarocks install luajson

Installing https://luarocks.org/luajson-1.3.4-1.src.rock    
luajson 1.3.4-1 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.1-1 provided by VM)
luajson 1.3.4-1 depends on lpeg >= 0.8.1 (1.1.0-1 installed)
Do not use 'module' as a build type. Use 'builtin' instead.
luajson 1.3.4-1 is now installed in /usr/local (license: MIT/X11)

My output after
 # lua test.lua

is this
lua: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/json/decode/util.lua:97: attempt to call field 'version' (a string value)
stack traceback:
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/json/decode/util.lua:97: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/json/decode.lua:12: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/json.lua:5: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    awattar.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: ?

Whats the problem here?

There was a bug in luajson, that was fixed in the source code at GitHub but not in the luarocks package.
Installing from GitHub (e.g., git clone https://github.com/harningt/luajson.git && cp -r luajson/lua /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/json && rm -r luajson or using sparse checkout) may help.

I changed from Lua5.1 to Lua5.4 and is did work there out of the box.

So I did not test your suggestion but it sounds legit.
